# Need help on mySql on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, xcode, macos, operating-system

I am new to Mac os world. I am having Mac OS 10.5.3 and I have installed mySql 5.5.8 in the system. It is installed in System preferences as well and I have Started the server from there. But the problem I am facing is that how to open mySql and start working on it. I am struggling a lot in order to finding the right thing to start mySql.

Please let me know if you need more info about my problem.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

-Ankit

Comment: How did you install **MySQL** into System **Preferences**? You're not making much sense here. And why the strange capitalization?

Comment: @coreyward. I think if you install MySQL from a dmg install you do get some System Preference panel installed as well.

Comment: @Coreyward: using the dmg file I installed the mySQL into System Preference. There is one file named MySQL.prefPane. Using this file I installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you only install mysql of any webserver too??

I have install XAMPP Apache server on MAC with php and mysql

try http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/

Comment: I am unable to connect to the ip provided by you. and yes I have installed mySql only into the machine using .dmg file.

Comment: what exactly you want... where you want to use the database

Comment: if you are not able to connect with your ip then try localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Actually I am working on a POC for native app. So there I want to connect my native app with the database. But in actual scenario we will be creating web service in order to connect to database. It's a kind of travel ticket booking app where I have "From" and "To" cities which I will populate from DB and will fetch the information based on the cities. I tried localhost and 127.0.0.1 as well but NO LUCK.. :(

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Amit. I tried again with 127.0.0.1 and this time I didn't provided any password and able to connect now.. thanks a  lot. :)

Comment: Now my task is to connect to the database with my native app.

Comment: if you want database locally on system then should use sqlite or data from a central server then create API and use it...

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a way to start accessing your MySQL database, you can use [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/), it's free.

If you're after a framework to connect to mysql using xcode/objective-c, checkout any of the [top search result from google](http://www.google.com.au/webhp?#hl=en&q=mysql+objective-c)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was trying to use Sequel Pro after installing the MySql. But I am unable to connect to the server. In the host I am giving my IP address and in the user name is am writing "root". Now when I click on Connect it gives "Connection Failed". Can you please help me out how to connect mysql using Sequel Pro.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of SequelPro as database management software for Mac :D. It was just was I looking for!